# How to merge lapply each record value to Final data frame

Tags: r

I have below R code which will iterate each text file which then fetches the respective parameter from each file and append it to the data frame.

Once the lapply get's over. I need a consolidated data frame in **Final**

How do I achieve this

```
files <- list.files(path="D:/Test/R/PBC", pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)

lapply(files, function(x) {

        text <- x       
        
        policy_nr <- str_extract(text,"(?<=Contract Number \\: )\\d+")
        
        if( is.na(policy_nr) == TRUE )
        {
          policy_nr <- str_extract(text,"(?<=Policy Number \\: )\\d+")
        }

        advisor_code <- str_extract(text,"(?<=Advisor Code \\: )\\d+")

        if( is.na(advisor_code) == TRUE )
        {
          advisor_code <- str_extract(text,"(?<=Advisor Code: )\\d+")
        }       

        data <- data.frame(PolicyNumber=policy_nr,AdvisorCode=advisor_code)
        
        


}
)

Final <- ?
```

Comment: `Final <- dplyr::bind_rows(lapply files, ...)`. Or pick another method from the marked dupe, you can use `do.call` and `rbind` if you want to not have a `dplyr` dependency.

Comment: As a style suggestion, `== TRUE` is almost never needed. `is.na` returns TRUE or FALSE, so you can simplify your `if` statements to, e.g., `if(is.na(policy_nr))`.

Comment: Hi Gregor..Thanks it worked

Comment: Hi Gregor .. In the same code after data <- data.frame.......  line ... I am trying this....  if ( is.na(policy_nr) &&  is.na(advisor_code) )
  {
  
   
   file_move("x","/Success")
  
  }       But I am not able to move.... Any help on this

Comment: Please ask a new question and share a little bit of sample data. `if()` and `&&` are good for checking a single value, not a vector/column of values. It's hard to understand what you're trying to do down here in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
files <- list.files(path="D:/Test/R/PBC", pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)

process <- lapply(files, function(text) {
  
  policy_nr <- str_extract(text,"(?<=Contract Number \\: )\\d+")

  if (is.na(policy_nr)) {
    policy_nr <- str_extract(text,"(?<=Policy Number \\: )\\d+")
  }

  advisor_code <- str_extract(text,"(?<=Advisor Code \\: )\\d+")

  if (is.na(advisor_code)) {
    advisor_code <- str_extract(text,"(?<=Advisor Code: )\\d+")
  }
  
  data.frame("PolicyNumber" = policy_nr, "AdvisoryCode" = advisor_code)
  
})

Final <- do.call(rbind, process)
```

Comment: Hi Merjin.. Any Ideaa how to move current file to Working directory sub folder named Success..... if ( is.na(policy_nr) && is.na(advisor_code) ) { file_move("x","/Success") } .. I tried this ..but no luck

Comment: Try not to make one specific question an ongoing process of all questions you encounter to get your final solution along the road. Have you tried to simply move any file to test your code. Simply make a test file and try to move it to another folder.